# How to iterate over rows from column1 and modify column2 depending on whether regex is matched in column1?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wish to add a column to my document indicating whether or not my regex was matched in another column. Such as to go from:

| Column A |
| --- |
| word regex word |
| word word word |
| word word word |
| word regex word |

to

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| word regex word | True |
| word word word | False |
| word word word | False |
| word regex word | True |

I doubled checked my regex and it works just fine, so the problem does not come from that.

I tried

1. iterating over the rows and changing them depending on whether the regex is matched

```
for row in FILE.itertuples():
       if FILE.COLUMNTOSEARCH.contains(REGEX):
            FILE.at[row.Index, "NEWCOLUMN"] = "string1"
       else:
            FILE.at[row.Index, "NEWCOLUMN"] = "string2"
```

This returns the error: "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'"

2. duplicating the first column and then using replace

```
FILE.replace(REGEX, regex=True, value="string1", inplace=True)
FILE.replace(REGEX, regex=False, value="string2", inplace=True)
```

For this, only the "string1" appears, and it doesnt replace the whole row, just where the regex is found although I wish to for "string1" to be the only string in the entry.

I've looked at all the stackoverflow possible + documentation without being able to figure anything. I feel like both those solutions are highly inefficient but cannot understand how to write something better. Thanks in advance for any help/solution.

Comment: No need to iterate, go vectorial: `df["Column B"] = df["Column A"].str.contains(REGEX)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.str.contains`:

```py
df["Column B"] = df["Column A"].str.contains(r"\bregex\b")
```

This outputs:

```py
          Column A  Column B
0  word regex word      True
1  word word word      False
2  word word word      False
3  word regex word      True
```